# Remove duplicate values from array of arrays, keeping one copy of each unique value

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array, unique

I have an array of hashes, each containing a large array in excess of 100,000+ elements.

I wrote this method to remove the duplicates from each of the inner arrays, *keeping only one copy of the element*, but sadly it is unusable with these large arrays since the array `-` operator is so expensive.

The data structure that I'm trying to reduce looks like this:

`[{regex: "st.+", results: ["string1", "string2", "strong"]}, 
{regex: "string.+", results: ["string1", "string2"]}]`

For clarification, the :regex was a regex used to find strings from a large array. This is why similar regexes can result in duplicate values between arrays.

```
def uniqify(arr)
# This loops over an arry of arrays and compares each 
# array to the next, keeping only the unique values in each array
  i = 0
  while i < arr.length
    a = arr[i][:results]
    j = i + 1
    while j < arr.length
      b = arr[j][:results]
      arr[j][:results] = b - a
      j += 1
    end
    i += 1
  end
  arr
end
```

The expected output for my example data should be:

`[{regex: "st.+", results: ["string1", "string2", "strong"]}, 
{regex: "string.+", results: []}]`

How can I make this loop function better?

Comment: Just to clarify, for my uses, it doesn't matter which array has the unique value, it only matters that each value is represented once across the entire array of arrays.

Comment: do you still need to keep the array groups, or can the unique values be represented by one-dimensional array?

Comment: I still have to keep the unique values in groups. This is because the unique values that aren't shared with any other arrays relate to a hash that I have to correlate this data with.

Comment: Not sure I understand since you are stating it does not matter where the unique is how do you intend to correlate? maybe a better explanation is needed. I think what @YevgeniyGoyfman was getting at is `arr.flatten.uniq`

Comment: Shoot. I left out something that would help clear all of this up. I'll revise the question.

Comment: @enginnermnky -- yes, that's exactly what I was going to suggest if array structure could be flattened.

Comment: Wouldn't a database of some sort be more appropriate when working with this much data?

Comment: Agreed, if you're dealing with huge arrays, you should use a database to offload the task of determining uniqueness. That will probably result in some speed-up of your code too.

Comment: To help potential answerers, you need to show what your expected output array would be. You also need to write some benchmarks to test various ways of implementing your code. Thinking you can write something that's faster than the built-in `-` might not be a good assumption, which benchmarks will show.

Comment: I'll see if I can add some benchmarks later tonight once I get home, I really like the possible solution offered by @tim-destan so I'm optimistic to see what kind of improvements I can get. Also, the reason I didn't include a benchmark to start out with is that the code (as it is written now) exceeded the 30 minute limit I set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of your problem is that you are doing O(n^2) array subtractions (for each array, you check all the other arrays in front of it, which is a lot of wasted effort). One improvement might be to keep one set that contains everything you've seen along the way. This requires processing each array only once, plus sets can cheaply check whether they contain an element.

```
require 'set'

def uniquify!(arrays)
  seen = Set.new
  arrays.each do |array|
    i = 0
    while i < array.length
      current = array[i]
      if seen.include? current
        array.delete_at(i)
      else
        seen.add(current)
        i += 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This modifies the argument array in-place (hence why I added the trailing `!` to the name).